# Change QTableWidget Item data for correct row

Tags: python, pyside

How can I properly update the data for a specific row in my QTableWidget while sorting is enabled. I noticed when I change the data of the column which the sorting is enabled for, the rows are immediately reordered, as a result the data for the second column is placed in the wrong row.

Here is the the starting screenshot:

[image]

Next i double click row C in order to edit it as seen here:

[image]

Now you'll see it properly changed the data in column 0 to display ZZZ however the second column text is now in the wrong row. How can i fix this?

[image]

```
import os, sys, json
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class TokenEditorDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, key, value, parent=None):
        super(TokenEditorDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300,50)

        self.uiKey = QtGui.QLineEdit(key)
        self.uiValue = QtGui.QLineEdit(value)

        self.uiOk = QtGui.QPushButton('OK')
        self.uiCancel = QtGui.QPushButton('Cancel')

        self.uiButtons = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox()
        self.uiButtons.addButton(self.uiOk, QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)
        self.uiButtons.addButton(self.uiCancel, QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)

        self.layout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        self.layout.addRow('Key', self.uiKey)
        self.layout.addRow('Value', self.uiValue)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiButtons)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # connections
        self.uiOk.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.uiCancel.clicked.connect(self.close)


class TokenEditorWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, tokens, parent=None):
        super(TokenEditorWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Token Editor')

        # privates
        self.uiView = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.uiView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.uiView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.uiView.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.uiView.horizontalHeader().show()
        self.uiView.setShowGrid(False)
        self.uiView.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiView.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.uiView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

        self.selection = self.uiView.selectionModel()

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.createActions()
        self.createMenus()

        # connections
        self.selection.selectionChanged.connect(self.updateControls)
        self.uiView.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.editSelectedItem)
        self.uiView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showContextMenu)

        # initialize
        self.setTokens(tokens)
        self.updateControls()


    def setTokens(self, tokens):
        '''
        Description:
            Loop through tuples and append table
        '''
        self.uiView.setColumnCount(2)
        self.uiView.setRowCount(0)
        self.uiView.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Key', 'Value'])
        for k, v in tokens:
            rowIndex = self.uiView.rowCount()
            self.uiView.insertRow(rowIndex)
            self.uiView.setItem(rowIndex, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(k))
            self.uiView.setItem(rowIndex, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(v))
        self.uiView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.uiView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.uiView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)


    def updateControls(self):
        state = len(self.selection.selectedRows())

        self.act_remove.setEnabled( state >= 1)
        self.act_edit.setEnabled( state == 1)


    def createActions(self):
        self.act_add = QtGui.QAction('Add New...', self)
        # self.act_add.triggered.connect(self.saveHotkeysPreset)

        self.act_edit = QtGui.QAction('Edit...', self)
        self.act_edit.triggered.connect(self.editSelectedItem)

        self.act_remove = QtGui.QAction('Remove', self)
        self.act_remove.triggered.connect(self.removeSelectedItems)

        self.act_clear = QtGui.QAction('Clear', self)
        self.act_clear.triggered.connect(self.clearItems)


    def createMenus(self):
        self.file_menu = QtGui.QMenu('File')
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.act_add)
        self.file_menu.addSeparator()
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.act_edit)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.act_remove)
        self.file_menu.addSeparator()
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.act_clear)
        # self.menuBar().addMenu(self.file_menu)

        menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        menuBar.addMenu(self.file_menu)
        self.layout.setMenuBar(menuBar)


    def removeSelectedItems(self):
        indices = []

        selectedRows = self.selection.selectedRows()
        for x in selectedRows:
            indices.append(QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(x))

        for x in indices:
            self.uiView.removeRow(x.row())


    def clearItems(self):
        self.setTokens([])


    def showContextMenu(self):
        self.file_menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())


    def editSelectedItem(self):
        selectedRows = self.selection.selectedRows()
        if selectedRows:
            # rowIndex = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(selectedRows[0])
            rowIndex = selectedRows[0].row()

            key = self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 0).text()
            value = self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 1).text()

            dlg = TokenEditorDialog(key, value, parent=self)
            if dlg.exec_():
                self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 0).setText(dlg.uiKey.text())
                self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 1).setText(dlg.uiValue.text())


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TokenEditorWidget(
        tokens=[
            ('A', 'Description'),
            ('B', 'Description'),
            ('C', 'Description'),
            ('D', 'Description'),
            ('E', 'Description'),
            ('F', 'Description'),
        ],
    )
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I believe, is that as the first column item is modified the table performs sorting, then the second item is modified. Probably the signal 'dataChanged' is connected to the sorting.

My solution is constrained to your code, it's not probably the best way to do it. I usually prefer writing my own model-view classes for this kind of things.

You only need to modify your `editSelectedItem` method as it follows:

```
def editSelectedItem(self):
    selectedRows = self.selection.selectedRows()
    if selectedRows:
        # rowIndex = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(selectedRows[0])
        rowIndex = selectedRows[0].row()

        key = self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 0).text()
        value = self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 1).text()

        dlg = TokenEditorDialog(key, value, parent=self)
        if dlg.exec_():
            # this line retrieves the current column index of the sorting on the table
            icol = self.uiView.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorSection()
            if icol == 0:
                self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 1).setText(dlg.uiValue.text())
                self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 0).setText(dlg.uiKey.text())
            elif icol == 1:
                self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 0).setText(dlg.uiKey.text())
                self.uiView.item(rowIndex, 1).setText(dlg.uiValue.text())
            else:
                # if you want to add more cases
                pass
```

I hope it helps.